# Quantum corrections to holographic entanglement entropy

Tags: gravity, string-theory, ads-cft, entanglement-entropy

I was looking at this [paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1307.2892) by Faulkner-Lewkowycz-Maldacena. They give a very interesting proposal of calculating one loop (i.e, 1/N) correction to EE from computing the EE between the bulk regions. The proposal is really fascinating. But I didn't quite realize few things.

1. What was the motivation behind this proposal? I mean why should one expect that 'this quantity' must be 1/N corrections?
2. What exactly one has to compute in the bulk geometry? They have some examples in the paper but I couldn't understand how to calculate the EE between bulk regions. Can someone refer to some articles where some concrete calculations have been done in this direction?

Comment: holographic EE via Ryu-Takayanagi is a statement that EE is given by areas of classical bulk geometry. Classical geometry is only an approximation to the bulk quantum gravity theory that only works in the large N limit, hence one would naturally expect quantum corrections.

Comment: @bechira I understand why there should be quantum corrections. I was wondering why that particular quantity should be the one loop correction? Is there any easier (may be very naive) way to see this?

Comment: Are you asking whether there's a easier way to do what they do in section 2.2 of that paper? If that's the case I doubt it.

Comment: Yes. Usually people conjecture something with some motivations/anticipations. Those may be very crude or naive. I didn't realize why one even should expect such a thing! May be I am not smart enough. :)